# How to use filelist as fileset in uptodate Ant command?

Tags: ant, dependencies, filelist, fileset

I have a target of `build.xml` that creates a Zip file. To avoid creating the Zip if no file has been updated, I'd like to check for updates beforehand. AFAIK, `uptodate` is the task to use.

Here is the relevant (simplified) script sections:

```
<filelist id="zip-files">
<file name="C:/main.exe" />
<file name="D:/other.dll" />
</filelist>

<target name="zip" depends="zip-check" unless="zip-uptodate">
<zip destfile="${zip-file}" >
    <filelist refid="zip-files" />
</zip>
</target>

<target name="zip-check">
 <uptodate property="zip-uptodate"
           targetfile="${zip-file}">
    <srcfiles refid="zip-files" />
 </uptodate>
</target>
```

However, `uptodate` fails because `srcfiles` must reference a `fileset`, not a `filelist`.  Still, I can't use a `fileset` because it would require a `dir` attribute, which I can't set because source files do not share a base directory.

Of course, I could just copy all files to a common directory before zipping them, thus being able to use `fileset`, but I was wondering whether there was an alternative solution.

I'm using Ant 1.8.1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using `<srcfiles>`, try using `<srcresources>`. `<srcfiles>` must be a fileset, but `<srcresource>` can be a union of any collection of resources, and that should include a `filelist`.

I can't do any test right now, but it should look something like this:

```
<filelist id="zip-files">
    <file name="C:/main.exe" />
    <file name="D:/other.dll" />
 </filelist>

 <target name="zip" depends="zip-check" unless="zip-uptodate">
     <zip destfile="${zip-file}" >
         <filelist refid="zip-files" />
     </zip>
</target>

<target name="zip-check">

    <union id="zip-union">
        <filelist refid="zip-files"/>
    </union>

    <uptodate property="zip-uptodate"
        targetfile="${zip-file}">
        <srcresources refid="zip-union" />
    </uptodate>
 </target>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: It works, thanks.  I don't know how to mark this topic "solved" by you, sorry.

Comment: There's a white check under the "number of votes" for the answer. Click on the check mark, and it'll turn green meaning the question has been answered.